# ImageIO.read() not working for unknown reason

Tags: java, io, lwjgl

```
try {
    System.out.println(new File(filename).exists());
    bi = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
    int height = bi.getHeight();
    int width = bi.getWidth();

    int[] raw_pixels = bi.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

    ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * 4);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            int pixel = raw_pixels[i * height + j];

            pixels.put( (byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xff) );
            pixels.put( (byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xff) );
            pixels.put( (byte) (pixel & 0xff) );
            pixels.put( (byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xff) );
        }
    }

    pixels.flip();

    id = glGenTextures();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
} catch (IOException e) {
    printStackTrace();
}
```

I have no clue why but the ImageIO.read() just stops the program and it won't read past it unless I comment it out. it prints true so I know that the path works but the ImageIO just breaks.

EDIT: when I say just stops I mean the JVM doesn't run the next line and if I pause it in debug mode it stopped on this.

```
    native void load(String name, boolean isBuiltin);
```

which is line 1736 on the abstract class ClassLoader
It stays on the line for hours and it won't continue

EDIT 2: if i just run the class without glfw i get this error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8ae6aa07, pid=4914, tid=0x0000000000001c03
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libGL.dylib+0x1a07]  glGetError+0xd
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# [path to project]/hs_err_pid4914.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Breaks how? If it's throwing an exception, what is it?

Comment: @yshavit it's not throwing an exception the code just stops and the only way to close the program is to terminate the JVM. the window I make with glfw just goes black. I'm new to glfw so I don't know if I didn't something wrong here, but if comment out everything in the class except the ImageIO it still breaks.

Comment: If it's not getting past that second line, presumably lwjgl (and all the code beyond the second line) is irrelevant. Are you able to reproduce this in a [mcve] (e.g. a simple console app)?

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for the suggestion I actually got a very interesting output from the JVM

Comment: Thank you for updating the question; I've voted to reopen it. If you can, it might help to also find in the debugger which class name it's trying to load there, as well as the full stack trace (you can just do `new Exception ().printStackTrace()` from the debugger).

Comment: I managed to figure it out. apparently, AWT and glfw interfere with each other, so I have to use STBImage instead of ImageIO.

note this is only a problem on macOS